# Conditional type checking at compile time in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

[Here is the corresponding TS playground.](https://tsplay.dev/wOxk7N)

The following function uses runtime checking to determine whether its input is a string or a number. Can the same be achieved at compile time?

```
type complex = string | number;

function fun(c: complex) {
    if (typeof c === "string") {
        return "c is string";
    }
    return "c is number";
}

console.log(fun("abc"));
console.log(fun(123));
```

---

**Background:** I want to create a React-Element which accepts a ReactNode as its child and should wrap it in a paragraph when ReactNode is a string. Wrapping should not occur when the child is not a string.

[Here is the corresponding React Playground.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-template-forked-s6i7x5?file=/src/index.tsx)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

type FunProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
const Fun = ({ children }: FunProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {typeof children === "string" && (
        <p style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{children}</p>
      )}
      {typeof children !== "string" && children}
    </>
  );
};

render(
  <>
    <Fun>{"123"}</Fun>
    <Fun>{123}</Fun>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is for compile time types, the types won't affect the runtime behaviour. You cannot use Typescript to automatically run a different function depending on the input type, you will need some conditional to achieve this functionality (similar to the one in your examples)

If you want it "at compile time", you could split the `Fun` component to two different components which each accepts either a `string` or a `number`. Typescript will then ensure that you call it with the correct type and it is done at compile time by simply calling a different function at compile time. For instance:

```
const FunString = ({ children }: { children: string }) => <p>string: {children}</p>
const FunNumber = ({ children }: { children: number }) => <p>number: {children}</p>

render(
  <>
    <FunString>{"123"}</FunString>
    <FunNumber>{123}</FunNumber>
    {/* Wrong usage by developer results in: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' */}
    <FunString>{123}</FunString>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Function overloading does not work like that in Typescript.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean or you understand what I meant. I've meant that instead of `Fun` you split it into two functions (`FunNumber`, `FunString`) and then use these accordingly (`<FunNumber>{123}</FunNumber>` and `<FunString>{"123"}</FunString>`)

Comment: "and then use these accordingly" That is exactly the problem ;)

Comment: I've added the code example which shows how Typescript prevents wrong usage by developers (but of course, it does not guarantee at compile time that if eg an API returns a string instead of a number it switches the function accordingly at runtime)

Comment: If this is not what you're looking for, please elaborate your problem. As said before, I probably don't understand what you want which means you need to explain it more clearly if you want a useful response from me

Answer (score -1):

Because it is a functional component, i.e. it should be typed as a function.

Type this function that children is a string

```
type FunProps = {
  children: string;
};

const Fun = ({ children }: FunProps) => {
  return (
    <p style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{children}</p>
  );
};

render(
  <>
    <Fun>{"123"}</Fun>
    <Fun>{123}</Fun>
    <Fun><div>555</div></Fun>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: This puts the `<div>` and `number` in a paragraph which is neither what I want nor is it valid Typescript.

Comment: TypeScript will not prevent rendering, but it will show an error at the time of building the application.

If you are not sure about the data that can get into the component, then you need to check inside the component that it is a string.
Please note that codesandbox.io just swears at the transfer of children